# Trying to add Window Domain User in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I saw SQL Server has provisions to add Window Domain User that are present in their domain.

Is there any way to do the same in MySQL?

Comment: short answer, it's a commercial part of MySQL

Answer (score 0):

It's a commercial add on to MySQL

[MySQL Windows Authentication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-pluggable-authentication.html)

In a pinch , you can use the `LDAP` module as Windows server is `LDAP` compatible.